# Creating multiple pages from design using bulk in Canva

Tags: canva

I am trying to create multiple pages in a design using bulk create.

However, after uploading the data I get a button with the text "Generate 20 designs" instead of "Generate 20 pages".
When I click it I don't get 20 pages. Instead I get a separate video with all the pages already built.
What am I missing?